# Vertically centered element with minimum margin/padding above it?

Tags: html, css

I have a vertically centered slideshow on a page, however I want to somehow add a "limit" so to speak on how high it slides up the page on smaller screens.

http://www.visioncreativegroup.com.au/demos/bps/index.php/production/theatre

If you resize your window, it will reach a point where the slideshow sits over the top of the navigation bar and the main logo. Basically it needs to stop at the base of these elements once the screen size reaches a small enough size.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hmm easy with JavaScript/JQuery - is that an option?

Comment: Yeah. Any solution is a good solution!

Comment: What happens when the window is smaller - does the slideshow get cut off, or does the footer go below the fold?

Comment: The footer is fixed and can cover up the slideshow from below. That's ok. But the slideshow overlaps the navigation bar once the window reaches a small enough height. I need it to stop moving with the vertical centering once it "hits" the bottom of the navigation bar so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

remove `position: absolute;` from `.production-scroll` class

Also remove `position: fixed;` from `#sticky-footer` if it is not necessary

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it still needs to be centered and removing that line changes that. :)

Comment: Fixed footer is also necessary. The client insists upon it unfortunately, such a pain in the neck!

Comment: @Tim your footer is too big and it surely gonna overlap on the banner if the screen is small. You need to decide between footer or banner. What's more important. There is another way to make the footer small :)

Comment: Yeah. I know. We tried telling the client that but he said it's okay if the footer overlaps the slideshow. I'm thinking I might need to use some jQuery - once the window reaches a certain height, I'll tweak the positioning of the slideshow or something.

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the slideshow section of the site, and the header section. So you have 3 horizontal slices: header, slideshow, footer. Then you can center the slideshow in the middle segment, and it will never go over the header.

Answer (score 0):

Give this small demo I've set up for you a try and see if you can switch up the HTML in your project to something similar:

`HTML:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Demo</title>

            <!-- Insert below CSS here -->
            <!-- Insert JQuery here (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js) -->
            <!-- Insert below JS here -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="shell">
            <div id="head">Header.</div>
            <div id="slideshow">Slideshow.</div>
            <div id="foot">Footer.</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`CSS:` (mainly for demonstration):

```css
*{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }
div#head{ height: 200px; background: blue; }
div#foot{ height: 100px; background: red; }
div#slideshow{ height: 300px; background: green; }
```

`JavaScript:`

```
// Fix position initially and on each window resize.
$(window).resize(fix);
$(document).ready(fix);

function fix()
{
    // Work out position value.
    var base = $("div#slideshow").position().top;
    var middle = $(window).height() / 2;
    var hw = $("div#slideshow").height() / 2;

    // Position top either at the position determined above, or 0 if it bypasses the top of the page.
    var destination = Math.max(middle - base - hw, 0);
    $("div#shell").offset({ top: destination });
}
```

[You can grab the full working example here](http://pastebin.com/DmKCie8x).